# OCaml : for loop inside if Statement

Tags: if-statement, for-loop, ocaml

I'm newbie in OCaml, what's wrong here (*Synthax error*):

```
let summry var3 =
    if var3 > 1 then 
        var4=var3
        for i = var4-1 downto 0 do var3=var3+i done;; 
    else if var3 == 1 then var3 = 1;;
    else var3 = 0 ;;
```

Is possibile the for loop inside if ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should only type `;;` when you want the toplevel (the OCaml interpreter) to evaluate what you've typed so far. If you enter `;;` partway through a syntactic construct you can't expect the following text to be part of what you've typed so far. Also, you need to separate expressions with `;`. You need parentheses or begin/end if you want two expressions after `then`.

In other words, this should fix the syntactic problems:

```
let summry var3 =
    if var3 > 1 then begin
        var4=var3;
        for i = var4-1 downto 0 do var3=var3+i done
    end
    else if var3 == 1 then var3 = 1
    else var3 = 0
```

This should fix the syntax, but you have other problems. The two that I see right off are (a) the OCaml operator `=` is used to compare values, not to assign values as you expect; (b) your code is written in an imperative style, and expects to change the values of variables using assignment. OCaml variables are immutable. You can't change their values unless you specifically use a mutable type for them.

Comment: Ok perfect, so the possibile way, for example,  to assign var3 to var4,I've to use let?Sorry but I'm really noob

Comment: `let` introduces a new immutable local variable, it doesn't assign to an existing variable. To modify values you need something mutable, such as a [reference](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/coreexamples.html#sec12). But let me encourage you to learn to write functional code if you have the time, that's one of the best reasons to study OCaml.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove those `;;`

`;;` is a toplevel token, it means "end of declaration" and cannot be put in the middle of an expression.

It is a common mistake to confuse it for a lot of language's `;` but should rather be thought as a "get back to global scope" instruction.